# Can I program ATTINY using Arduino as ISP whilst having other I2C devices connected?

Tags: i2c, attiny85, arduinoisp

I have an SMD ATTINY that I'm using for a project. Attached to it are 3 I2C devices. When programming it using an Arduino as an ISP, can I have those devices attached? Ie, do I have to program the ATTINY and then solder it on my board or can I solder it and the program (and re-program if necessary).

Comment: why don't you just try it? ..  you said that the I2C devices are already connected

Comment: @jsotola - Maybe because he'd rather not risk damaging something in case someone else already knows?

Comment: Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please [edit] your question and add the schematic, so we can see how you connect the I²C devices, together with the ISP connector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the slave devices shouldn't respond unless addressed. When programming, data will obviously be on the lines however the probability of this data accidentally containing the right sequence to correctly query a slave is minimal.

Comment: Did you consider that devices are allowed to stretch any low clock pulse?